# Django logging does not write debug.log file issue

Tags: django, debugging, logging

I just set up new server and while I'm checking it, I got 500 error. I expect that debug.log file has error message, However, when I check the file the file was empty. Nothing was written. So I changed the loggers settings may times, but still the file is empty and I can't fix the error because what is wrong with it...

This is my views.py

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

put this line to do logging.

settings.py

```
LOGGING = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': False,
'filters': {
    'require_debug_false': {
        '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
    }
},
'formatters': {
    'simple': {
        'format': '%(asctime)s %(filename)s:%(lineno)d %(message)s',
    }
},
'handlers': {
    'file': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
        'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
        'filename': '/var/log/service/debug.log',
        'formatter': 'simple',
    },
},
'loggers': {
    'django': {
        'handlers': ['file'],
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'propagate': True,
    },
}
}

if DEBUG:
    del LOGGING['loggers']['django']
    del LOGGING['handlers']['file']

if not os.path.exists('log'):
    os.makedirs('log')
```

I attached my wsgi.py

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

This is settings.py where import local settings.

```
try:
    from local_settings import *
except ImportError:
    raise ImportError('You must create local_settings.py on project root')
```

This is local_settings.py

```
DEBUG=False
```

Comment: How are you using the logger object you created?

Comment: @ShahrukhMohammad logger object?

Comment: The one you created in your views.py file

Answer (score 4):

You don't have logger named `views` in your settings. It's only logger named `django` there. So try to use it in views.py:

```
logger = logging.getLogger('django')
```

Comment: @camila did you restart Django after changes?

Comment: I restarted uwsgi so yeah, I restarted Django after changes.

Comment: Thank you very much I was not passing logger name & it took 2-3 hours to find me this answer. It works!

Answer (score 0):

what is the setting of `DEBUG` on your server?

because:

`if DEBUG:
    del LOGGING['loggers']['django']
    del LOGGING['handlers']['file']`

if `DEBUG` is `True` you are deleting the logger and handler...

Comment: just checked, settings.py debug is True but I made local_settings.py, in here DEBUG=False.

Comment: are you sure you are loading local_settings.py? are you setting the environment variable or did you modify the wsgi.py? details...

Comment: I attached wsgi.py.

Comment: I still do not see where you are loading local_settings like you mentioned. Are you setting the environment variable?